# Unit test an exception being thrown from RX errorHandler - kotlin/java

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, error-handling, rx-java

I'm writing a unit test which is testing a scenario an exception is being thrown from RX.
I do have an Rx errorHandler, and I want to throw the exception in this case.

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { it : Throwable -> 
     if(it meets the condition){
         throw it
     }
}
```

How do I catch the exception thrown in the unit test so the test passes?
I keep getting 'UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with'.

Comment: For example, the error handler adds the exception to a list or field. In your test method, you check the list or field and throw its content.